# React Native Fetch API returning old data

Tags: android, react-native, fetch-api

my fetch API always returns the old json data. My app requests API for my user list, it works in the beginning, however when I post a new user, and refresh my list (call the same fetch function), it returned the same list (without new user). But it works whenever I totally close my apps, and re-open it. I wonder why this could happen. Do I need to "reset" my fetch API function? is there such function works like that?

Here is my fetch function:

```
fetch(GET_USER_SESSION, {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  }
})
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((data) => {
  return data // return same old list
}).catch((err) => this.showError('Error Signing Up, Please Try Again.'));
```

Any idea? thanks very much!

Comment: have you found the solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

add this to your headers in the fetch API: `'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'`